# Update state and call parent onChange handler simultaneously from child component during onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do two things when the child component's `select` element is changed-

1. update child state (used to display more fields and in other child-specific decisions etc.),
2. call parent handler passed in props.

Only 1st one is working, how do I add 2nd one also? Whats the proper way?

Dummy code:

```
class Child {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            //....
            <select 
                id={this.state.searchId}
                value={this.state.searchId}
                onChange={
                    //1. event => this.setState({searchId : event.target.value})
                    //2. call parent props changeHandler
                }>
                {options}
            </select>
            //....
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Parent {
    onSearchPrefChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            searchId : e.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){
        <Child onChange={this.onSearchPrefChange} />
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
onChange={e => {
    this.setState({searchId : e.target.value});
    this.props.onSearchPrefChange;
}}>
```

The parent handler is not called, which also is used to change state of parent with same changed element's value/id.

Comment: what is happend now?

Comment: Edited question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `onChange` event handler in the child component, set child's set there and call the callback passed from the parent in `props` from the function. Here is example code:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSelectChange = this.onSelectChange.bind(this);
  }
  onSelectChange(e) {
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(newValue );
    // set child state here
    this.setState({searchId : newValue })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelectChange}>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  }
  someHandler(childValue) {
    console.log(childValue);
    this.setState({ value: childValue })
  }
  render() {
    return <Child onChange={this.someHandler} />
  }
}
```

Here is a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4qor74yr9).

Comment: Thanks Margaret, was common sense. As I am new to JS, often I find myself lost in the ocean of code that I have only written  :D

Comment: Glad to help! many people who write in JS on a regular basis find themselves lost in the JS code they have written ;)